# Toastr multiple divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, toastr

i have multiple divs that contain custom css toastr notification,
what i need help with is displaying random div each time page loads or using toastr by codeseven how to do it in same way, any help is appreciated either css or js, this is what i've been trying but no luck, and i have tried also to use math() for it but its either showing all divs at the same time or not even working... is there anyway it can select specific div and show only him while hiding other divs that are there?

```css
#toastr {
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity 1s 1s;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 17px;
  animation: fadeins 5s linear forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

#toastr a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#toastr>div {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  background-position: 15px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 1;
}

.toastr-success {
  background-color: #51A351;
}

@keyframes fadeins {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: -5px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 12px;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 12px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even random-popup">
  <div class="views-field views-field-nothing">
    <span class="field-content">
      <div id="toastr" class="toastr">
        <div class="toast toastr-success" aria-live="polite">
          <div class="toast-message"><a href="#">message1</a>.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-even random-popup">
  <div class="views-field views-field-nothing">
    <span class="field-content">
      <div id="toastr" class="toastr">
        <div class="toast toastr-success" aria-live="polite">
          <div class="toast-message"><a href="#">message2</a>.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen as you have a class called random-popup, you can set them to initially be display none, and then using another class maybe called active, set the display to block..

```
.random-popup {
  display: none;
}
.random-popup.active {
  display: block;
}
```

Then with a bit of simple Javascript to set one of them randomly visible by adding the active class..

```
var popups = document.querySelectorAll(".random-popup");
popups[Math.trunc(Math.random() * popups.length)].classList.add("active");
```

eg..

```js
var popups = document.querySelectorAll(".random-popup");

popups[Math.trunc(Math.random() * popups.length)]
  .classList.add("active");
```

```css
#toastr {
  font-size: 21px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity 1s 1s;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 17px;
  animation: fadeins 5s linear forwards;
  opacity: 0;
}

#toastr a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#toastr>div {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  background-position: 15px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  opacity: 1;
}

.toastr-success {
  background-color: #51A351;
}

@keyframes fadeins {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: -5px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 12px;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 12px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

.random-popup {
  display: none;
}

.random-popup.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even random-popup">
  <div class="views-field views-field-nothing">
    <span class="field-content">
      <div id="toastr" class="toastr">
        <div class="toast toastr-success" aria-live="polite">
          <div class="toast-message"><a href="#">message1</a>.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-even random-popup">
  <div class="views-field views-field-nothing">
    <span class="field-content">
      <div id="toastr" class="toastr">
        <div class="toast toastr-success" aria-live="polite">
          <div class="toast-message"><a href="#">message2</a>.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Somehow im getting "Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
"

Comment: Your maybe using a really rubbish browser.. :)    If so, you could substitute the above with say something like jQuery.   The above snippet for me is working in Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: And clicking the above `Run code snippet` say's 'classList' of undefined?

Comment: It's working here but not on website, nevermind ill find why isn't, it's working here in run code snippet, thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: If you mean your getting the error when you place this code inside you website, then make sure you place the Javascript after you have created the HTML bit, a good place the place the Script Tag, is just before the closing body tag.. `<script>code</script></body> `

Comment: (function ($) {

var popups = $(document.querySelectorAll(".random-popup"));
popups[Math.trunc(Math.random() * popups.length)].classList.add("active");

    })

Comment: Yes, you can use jQuery's dom ready too, but placing before the closing `</body>` tag would have the same effect too.